# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Query, return all records of a model and include a count of associated records in a single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have the following models:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  has_many :studies, :through => :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
  belongs_to :study
end

class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  has_many :keywords, :through => :tags
end
```

I want an array containing all of the keywords, and for each keyword, and count of the studies tagged with that keyword, so that I can say:

```
<ul>
<% @keywords.each do |keyword| %>
  <li><%= "(#{keyword.number_of_studies}) #{keyword.title}") %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I'm sure this is possible, the question is: how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the counter cache. This keeps an integer value on the parent object with the number of children. ActiveRecord keeps track.

```
class Post < AR::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < AR::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
end

@post.comments_count
```

If you really *must* use one query without the counter cache:

```
@post = Post.find(first, :select => 'posts.*, count(comments.id) as comments_count',:joins => 'left outer join comments on comments.post_id = posts.id', :group => 'posts.id')
@post.comments_count #=> From join query.
```

As you can see, this gets ugly fast. It's better to stick with the counter cache, or do two separate queries.

```
@post = Post.find(:first) # SELECT FROM posts
@post.comments.count      # SELECT COUNT(1) FROM comments WHERE post_id = ?
```

Comment: Ok, that definitely solves the problem.  I'm hoping for an ARel query of some sort though that will give me the count as part of the query when I get all keywords.  I gave you a vote.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with what you want. I'm still of the opinion that you should either use `counter_cache` or perform two queries. It makes your code a lot cleaner and less prone to errors.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, I can infer the Rails 3 ARel query syntax from what you've got, and what' you've got is exactly what I'm looking for.